# How to design subtype in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm working on a project that I should build a table of user. Each user has some user information such as username and password and so on. Besides, a "user type": New users are "newbie", 6 month users are "regular" and 1 year old users are "leader". These three types has a value of "karma" to store their score. There are also "moderator" type and "administrator" type, which instead of having "karma", they have a emergency contact number. The former one also has a value of degree.

[image: This is my model]

This is my model so far, but I have problem design the "user type". I'm thinking of a supertype/subtype solution, but it seems like I can't do that on the mysql workbench. Is there an alternative design for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, MySQL Workbench cannot model inheritance, as this is not supported by MySQL anyway. But why going to so complicated? Simply define the type as an attribute (field) on the user table. Use an enum to limit the acceptable values. You could also define a UserType table to which this attribute has a 1:n relationship and which can contain additional information per user type.

As a sidenote: your additional tables for the address seem to be overkill. How often will more than one user live at the same address? It's so uncommon that you can easily store the address in the user table as well without fearing significant denormalization. If that's opportune you can however use a country and a city table with relationships from the user table to them to normalize them. However that user_has_postalAddress table really seems to be superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for replying to an old post, but I am trying to find a good free ERD tool for the Mac, and MySQL Workbench is the best I've found.

The answer above says MySQL doesn't support super/sub types. I don't really agree with that assertion. This is, IMO, a limitation of MySQL Workbench. super/sub type can simply be modeled as an 1:N identifying relationship with a denormalization rule. The denormalization rule defines a difference between the logical model and the physical model. I don't see any way in MySQL workbench to model anything but the physical model.

Similarly, with address, Address and User would traditionally be two different entities and the value that the ERD tool should add is being able to change the relationship between them. N:M in the original post, or as in the reply, a 1:1 identifying with a denormalization rule to indicate that the Address fields should be denormalized into the User entity in the physical model. Or even a 1:N identifying if you want to have a shipping and billing address.

So, I assert that super/sub type modeling is not a limitation of MySQL, it's a limitation of MySQL Workbench. Relationships should support roll-up and roll-down denormalization rules.